# I want to create an endpoint like www.example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json on WordPress using php

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, endpoint

I'm creating a plugin and need to create endpoint like [www.example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json](http://www.example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json). it is necessary for my plugin to work and I don't know how to create endpoint on WordPress with php.
I used

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
            register_rest_route( '.well-known', '/assetlinks', array(
               'methods' => 'GET',
              'callback' => 'create_assetlinks_endpoint',
           ) );
       } );
```

But does not work this.
Can anybody help me out?
This is a json data need to create api endpoint.

```
[
    {
      "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
      "target": {
        "namespace": "android_app",
     "package_name": "com.bluebricks.passwordless",
        "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
     "E9:B5:61:8F:48:C8:62:4A:CC:70:C4:1F:B8:FA:E0:40:F0:68:68:D9:AF:F5:18:FC:6B:93:C8:53:5C:FB:0E:16"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
```

Comment: I'm unsure if hidden (prefixed with '.') folders are handled with the .htaccess mod_rewrite rules for WP.  Does the file need to be dynamic on every access?  If not, you could just write the file to that actual folder?

Comment: @flauntster file is static, but I'm trying to create a folder .well-known in root directory in that assetlinks.json file will be create automatically when plugin is activated. do you know is that possible or not?

Comment: You should just create the folder via FTP and store the json file in there.  Alternatively if you dont have FTP/SFTP access, you could use a WP plugin like WP File Manager to do this.

Comment: @flauntster yes I did that already and it worked

Comment: understand that letsencrypt (for aws lightsail at least) will make things more complicated. it creates a symlink to /opt/bitnami/apps/letsencrypt/.well-known - and rewrites many many apache conf files  but if you find it - you may be able to just copy file there.